# How to add a reference level for interaction in gtsummary and sjPlot

Tags: python, r, gtsummary, sjplot

I hope my question makes sense and I want to understand what is the reference level for interaction term/characteristic/predictors, etc.

```
Here is my code:
library(gtsummary)
library(sjPlot)


set.seed(1000)
my_data <- rbind(
  data.frame(time = "Pre", treatment = "Control", response = rnorm(100, mean=1)),
  data.frame(time = "Pre", treatment = "Treatment", response = rnorm(100, mean=2)),
  data.frame(time = "Post", treatment = "Control", response = rnorm(100, mean=1)),
  data.frame(time = "Post", treatment = "Treatment", response = rnorm(100, mean=2))
) %>% mutate(time = factor(time, levels = c("Pre", "Post"))) %>%
mutate(treatment = factor(treatment, levels = c("Control", "Treatment")))

model3 <- lm(response ~ time * treatment, data = my_data)


gtsummary::tbl_regression(model3,
  pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2),
  estimate_fun = ~ style_number(.x, digits = 4)
) %>%
  add_global_p() %>%
  bold_p(t = 0.10) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_levels()


sjPlot::tab_model(model3, show.reflvl = TRUE)
```

Which gives me:

[image]

I want to add a reference level (if possible) for interaction term to be explicitly visible and would be grateful for a bit of explanation how to interpret interaction effect here, I mean if it was statistically significant ?

In R usually those reference levels are hidden/omitted, but it would be good to include them in final summary table.

---

My desired table would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: With the `gtsummary::modify_table_body()` function, you can essentially make any modification you'd like. But I don't think that is something you really want to do. You reference a singular reference level, but there are actually 3: `Pre * Control`, `Pre * Treatment`, and `Post * Control`. Each of these combinations is a kind of reference group and I haven't seen published models that include these in tables summarizing regression model results.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I am beginner with gtsummery so would you be able please to show me how to add this to my code using gtsummary::modify_table_body() you mentioned, just for didactic purposes. And for clarification my timePost:treatmentTreatment interaction is compared to Pre * Control or Pre * Treatment or Post * Control individually or to all of three of them at once ?

Comment: I have checked and the same similar output is available in SPSS, so this is why I ask how to do that table which I presented in my OP question. Still trying, please help achieve my desired result and obviously I want to learn how to use gtsummary::modify_table_body().

Comment: Maybe this can be done in python if there is such difficulty to do it in R especially in gtsummary ?

Comment: Removed the Stata tag, which appears irrelevant.  How to interpret results statistically I take to be off-topic here, but the merits of this as a question about programming must be judged by people familiar with the language.

Comment: What you call reference levels are usually omitted, as it is non-sensical to include them. The interaction effect only comes into effect if both time and treatment are not 0 (interaction term = b3*x1*x2). Otherwise, the interaction term remains 0 as all other components are multiplied by 0. So when time is "post" and treatment is "treatment", y is changed by the interaction effect. I strongly advise to not include the other combinations for the interaction effect and to read up on statistics.

Comment: Yes, the key word is - "usually". I would like to know how to do it from programming, technical point of view. It can be done in SPSS, very easy and quick in Stata. I am interested if it can be done in R and how ?

Comment: I think @NickCox, Stata tag is relevant here: 
http://maartenbuis.nl/publications/ref_cat.html, quote: "When including a set of indicator variables (often called dummy variables) the standard approach is to leave one category out, the so-called reference category. It is possible to include an indicator variable for the reference category, and this can provide a useful alternative view on the same model. This idea can also be extended to interaction effects."
In full article there are examples of included ref. levels.
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1201200111

Comment: You really need to make the case in your question. We don't need to hear an argument that interactions are used in other statistical software! But if for example you're saying that you are interested in a Stata solution then spell that out.  FWIW, questions about one language asking for translations to another language (1) often are disapproved in principle (2) rarely work well for the OP in practice.  Tagging to try to widen the readership is not in my view a good idea.