# How to add reference level(s) for interaction in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, interaction, ggstatsplot

My question is connected with this:
[How to add a reference level for interaction in gtsummary and sjPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77933272/how-to-add-a-reference-level-for-interaction-in-gtsummary-and-sjplot/77935742#77935742)

for which I did not get a solution that I am still in need.
The code is as follows:

```
set.seed(1000)
my_data <- rbind(
  data.frame(time = "Pre", treatment = "Control", response = rnorm(100, mean=1)),
  data.frame(time = "Pre", treatment = "Treatment", response = rnorm(100, mean=2)),
  data.frame(time = "Post", treatment = "Control", response = rnorm(100, mean=1)),
  data.frame(time = "Post", treatment = "Treatment", response = rnorm(100, mean=2))
) %>% mutate(time = factor(time, levels = c("Pre", "Post"))) %>%
mutate(treatment = factor(treatment, levels = c("Control", "Treatment")))

model3 <- lm(response ~ time * treatment, data = my_data)
```

I have tried a different approach this time, meaning another package:

`library(ggstats)`
`ggstats::ggcoef_table(model3)`

for which I got following results:[image]

So my question is because ggcoef_table(model3) function has included reference levels for factor variables, would it be possible
to add reference levels for interaction as well using **ggstats** package or any other ?

Something to the effect of:

[image]

in order to have it (reference levels for interaction term) on the plot and this coefs table situated besides the plot.
I would be grateful for any help regarding this matter, thank you.